# Does final have to be elemental or bug in compiler

Tags: memory-management, fortran, destructor

In the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/e-to-f/final-statement.html) of ifort it says

> If the entity being finalized is an array, each finalizable component of each element of that array is finalized separately.

and there is no word about `elemental` being necessary.

But if I have a vector of finalizable components, there are memory leaks if the `final` procedure is not declares as elemental. (The memory leaks being reported by `valgrind`.)

```
module vector_mod
    implicit none(type, external)
    private
    public :: Vector_t

    type :: Vector_t
        real, pointer :: X(:) => null()
    contains
        procedure :: init
        final :: finalize
    end type

contains

    subroutine init(this, n, val)
        class(Vector_t), intent(out) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real, intent(in) :: val
        allocate(this%X(n), source=val)
    end subroutine

    ! If this elemental is missing I get memory leaks in
    ! - gfortran 7.5.0
    ! - ifort 19.1.1.217
    elemental subroutine finalize(this)
        type(Vector_t), intent(inout) :: this
        if (associated(this%X)) deallocate(this%X)
    end subroutine

end module

program test_final_intentout
    use vector_mod, only: Vector_t
    implicit none(type, external)
    block
        type(Vector_t), allocatable :: vectors(:)
        integer :: i
        allocate(vectors(3))

        do i = 1, size(vectors)
            call vectors(i)%init(i, 1.)
        end do
    end block
end program
```

Comment: Yes, I did have similar leaks using ifort which is why I dont use `final` no more...

Comment: To provide a final subroutine that covers both scalars and arrays then it needs to be elemental. Without being elemental but taking a scalar dummy, you don't have a final subroutine for an array object.

Comment: I'll try to find my old example where `final` was broken. I think it called that routine multiple times... it is definitely buggy, be warned!

Comment: @francescalcus makes sense. But then the ifort documentation is wrong (or at least misleading)

Comment: I think the ifort documentation is _correct_ if not _helpful_. That is, what happens is correct as it quotes the Fortran standard, but it fails to explain the background for what that means. This makes your question here a reasonable one (and I'd answer if there wasn't the other question covering it), but I'll say that the ifort (most compiler) documentation is a truly terrible way to learn how to use the Fortran language compared with a proper guide. (Sorry for the late reply: your @ had a misspelling.)